# Intercepting email to add text

Tags: email, exchange-server

I need to automatically add text to emails sent by users. The text CANNOT be added as a signature in outlook, but has to be added after the users click 'send' in outlook. My company uses Microsoft Exchange Server.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If this is Exchange Server 2007 you can add a thing called a [Transport Rule](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996585.aspx) (in the Exchange Management Console) to do this. What you're looking for is called a "disclaimer" since most companies do this so that they can add a legal disclaimer to the bottom of outgoing email.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that this could be done with a Microsoft Outlook add-in if you have access to be able to distribute such things.  Adding it as an addin at the client level may be easier than adding something to the server, and would certainly be less likely to cause problems with the server itself.

If memory serves, Visual Studio allows you the ability to create Microsoft Office addins.

Here's a link to an MSDN article about programming for Outlook 2003 in C#
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289167.aspx